# No me actualiza Ajax Json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel, json

en el select que muestra una lista desde una api en json

```
 <select id="Select"></select>
```

el se va al js

```
function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/api', 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
        $("#Select").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.primer_nombre+'</option>');
      });        
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('error');
    }

  });
}
```

El me muestra los valores sin problema pero no actualiza automáticamente y no muestra el ultimo creado.

Adicionalmente como escojo ese valor y lo envió mediante *post*.

Comment: ¿A que te referís con "El me muestra los valores sin problema pero no actualiza automáticamente y no muestra el ultimo creado."?

Comment: Yo por otra página realizo un registro enyonces, si realizo ese registro, debería mostrarme en ese select.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código, no veo nada raro, salvo que no lleguen los datos. de aqui no tengo forma de comprobar eso.
Por otra parte lo que se me hace raro es la forma en la que construyes el campo de select.

Por mi parte la genero de esta forma y reemplazándola en tu código quedaría algo así, podrías probar y decirme.

```
function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/api', 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data,function(key, registro) {
        $('#Select').append($('<option>', { 
          value: registro.id,
          text : registro.primer_nombre 
         }));
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('error');
    }
  });
```

}